# How to make AdaptiveMonteCarlo evaluate numerically the integrand?

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to efficiently estimate an integral on a hypersurface defined by equations.

My code is :

```
f[x_, y_] :=  x^2 + y^2 ;

eq1[x_, y_] := y^2 - x;

NIntegrate[
 sol = Solve[eq1[x, y] == 0 , y, Reals]; Sum[
(f[x, y]/Abs[D[eq1[x, y], y]]) /. {y -> (y /. sol)[[index]]}, {index, 1, Length[sol]}],
{x, -1, 1}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
```

And when I run it I get :
[image]

However my code runs correctly when the x boundaries are {0,1} or when I replace AdaptiveMonteCarlo by MonteCarlo.
So I think AdaptiveMonteCarlo solves the equation analytically for all x, then integrates, and a problem occurs as y gets undefined for negative values of x.

I would like it to solve the equation only for the samples x_i, that would remove my problem.

(I need to use a MonteCarlo method because my final integral should be of dimension 10, with 4 equations. This one is only a test.)

Answer (score 1):

Real solution of `eq1[x,y]==0` is only possible if `x>=0`

```
ContourPlot[eq1[x, y] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, FrameLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Perhaps that's the reason for the error "AdaptiveMonteCarlo" gives ?

If you omit the Method option, `NIntegrate[…,{x,-1,1}]` and `NIntegrate[…,{x,0,1}]` evaluate without error.

Comment: That's right. The problem is, AdaptiveMonteCarlo seems to solve eq1 analytically first, so that 'sol = {ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[x],x>=0], ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[x],x>=0]}'. Then it raises an error when sol is evaluated for x<0.

Comment: On the other hand, Montecarlo solves eq1 numerically, so 'sol = {Sqrt[x],-Sqrt[x]}' for all x>0 and 'sol = {}' if x<0. What I don't understand is why MonteCarlo and AdaptiveMonteCarlo behave differently

Answer (score 1):

I would like to alter the answer of @AntonAntonov, since it doesn't regard the condition.

Convert CondionalExpression to a Boole expression.
Just take the first four lines of Anton's code and then

```
NIntegrate[
   Evaluate[sol2 /. 
     ConditionalExpression[rr_, ss_] -> rr*Boole[ss]], {x, -1, 1}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"
]

(*   1.0644   *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the explanation of the message and lack of it for `"MonteCarlo"`:

> `NIntegrate::inumr`: The integrand
> `ConditionalExpression[(x + x^2)/Sqrt[Abs[x]], x > 0]` has evaluated
> to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with
> boundaries `` {{0,0.36`}} ``.

First of all, `NIntegrate` rescales the interval of integration to `{0, 1}`. This, unfortunately, is not well documented; there are hints, but I haven't found in the extensive documentation a statement of exactly when it is done, whether always or only sometimes.  What is more unfortunate is that the subinterval is not mapped back to the user-specified interval in the error message, which confuses the user. The subinterval of the user's integration interval `{-1, 1}` corresponding to the error would be given by

```
Rescale[{{0, 0.36}}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}]
(*  {{-1., -0.28}}  *)
```

The integrand `ConditionalExpression[(x + x^2)/Sqrt[Abs[x]], x > 0]` is undefined on this interval.  Hence the message.  Here is evidence for the claimed rescaling (we use a function `obj` that doesn't evaluate symbolically to see the effect on `x`):

```
obj[x_?NumericQ] = 
 Sum[(f[x, y]/Abs[D[eq1[x, y], y]]) /. s, {s, sol}];
Trace[
  NIntegrate[obj[x], {x, -1, 1}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"],
  _obj,
  TraceInternal -> True][[2]]
(*  {HoldForm[obj[-1 + 2*x]]}  *)
```

Second, `"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"` subdivides the interval but `"MonteCarlo"` does not.  The error is for "non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region," which is true for the subinterval reported in `"AdaptiveMonteCarlo"` but not true for the whole interval, which is used by `"MonteCarlo"`.  Non-numerical values are ignored if there are valid numerical values in a region.

Another gratuitous workaround:

```
ClearAll[extendCEbyZero];
extendCEbyZero[expr_] := PiecewiseExpand[expr] /.
    {ConditionalExpression[e_, c_] :> Piecewise[{{e, c}}],
     Undefined -> 0};

NIntegrate[
 extendCEbyZero@Sum[
   (f[x, y]/Abs[D[eq1[x, y], y]]) /. sol[[index]],
   {index, 1, Length[sol]}],
 {x, -1, 1}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
(*  1.06287  *)
```

Comment: Related to the posted "gratuitous workaround" -- "AdaptiveMonteCarlo" by default does not do symbolic pre-processing. Using, say, `NIntegrate[sol2, {x, -1, 1}, Method -> {"AdaptiveMonteCarlo", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 10}]` would produce an expected numerical result without messages. (Well, most of the time...)

Comment: I plan to update my answer accordingly this weekend...

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks, I didn't know about the symbolic processing. I haven't explored the Monte Carlo methods of `NIntegrate` very much or often.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer wrongly assumes that OP does not necessarily care for the conditions coming from `Solve`, just the solution expression to be used as an integrand. (See the comments and [Akku14's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235945).*

---

Just take the first element of the result of `Sum[...]` (`sol2` below):

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;

eq1[x_, y_] := y^2 - x;

sol = Solve[eq1[x, y] == 0, y, Reals]; 
sol2 = 
 Sum[(f[x, y]/Abs[D[eq1[x, y], y]]) /. {y -> (y /. sol)[[index]]}, {index, 1, 
   Length[sol]}]

Evaluate[sol2[[1]]]

NIntegrate[Evaluate[sol2[[1]]], {x, -1, 1}, Method -> "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"]
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, @AntonAntonov, this is not right. Condition says, x>0, but you also get a contribution from x<0, if you just take sol2[[1]]. The best way for me seems to convert ConditionalExpression to a Boole expression. See my answer.

Comment: @Akku14 Good point -- (+1) on [your answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235945). I saw that the condition says `x > 0`, but I missed OP's request: "I would like it to solve the equation only for the samples x_i, that would remove my problem." (I thought OP does not necessarily care for the conditions coming from `Solve`, just the solution expression to be used as an integrand...)